# ImageJ 16-bit Photo to tiff with values

Tags: tiff, imagej, temperature, 16-bit

I have a 16 bit signed raw photo and would like to export this image as a tiff with ImageJ. The RAW photo is displayed correctly and the displayed value (172.00) is also correct. What does the value behind the 172.00 in brackets mean? When I export the image to Tiff, only this value (32940) is exported and the 172.00 no longer appears. How can I transfer this value into the Tiff? Or can the value in brackets be converted somehow?

Thanks a lot!

[16-bit Signed RAW Photo with Temperature Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytnJz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with the display range being different from the actual 16-bit pixel value (32940).  ImageJ will display the images to you usually in the 0-255 range by default.  In principle, the 32940 value should be the correct one to use for your analysis, unless you have an exceptionally dim signal for a 16-bit image.  Check out the documentation here:

https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html